# One to One Mapping between two tables in Hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, aop, one-to-one

I have two tables

```
        CREATE TABLE `cb_jobs` (
    `JOB_IDENTIFIER` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `CB_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_IDENTIFIER` INT(11) NOT NULL
    `IS_DELETED` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`JOB_IDENTIFIER`),
    INDEX `FK_cb_jobs_cb_credential_type` (`CB_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_IDENTIFIER`)
    CONSTRAINT `FK_cb_jobs_cb_credential_type` FOREIGN KEY (`CB_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_IDENTIFIER`) REFERENCES `cb_credential_type` (`CB_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_IDENTIFIER`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETECASCADE)COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB;    
    CREATE TABLE `cb_credential_type` (
    `CB_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_IDENTIFIER` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `CB_CREDENTIAL_CODE` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CB_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_NAME` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CREATED_DATE` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CREATED_BY_USER` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPDATED_DATE` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPDATED_BY_USER` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `IS_DELETED` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`CB_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_IDENTIFIER`)
    )COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

I would like to get the details of 2nd table based on the credential type id.
How to write Hibernate mapping classes with one to one relationship using hibernate annotations.Anybody please help me.......

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial this might help you

http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-1.html

check the hibernate one-one annotated  tutorial

http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-using-annotations-1.html

Comment: Thanks Murali! But I need annotated one ! I have done this but the parameters are going wrong, and getting incorrect data.